# Проблемы с сокетом Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jsp, maven

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться с проблемой, есть локальная БД к которой локально обращается hibernate, бывает что день работает идеально не ошибок не обрывов, все быстро работает, но часто Hibernate стал рвать связь с сокетом, в чем может быть проблема ? Ошибки с логов Eclipse:

**1) org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection**

**2) Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Ошибка ввода/вывода: Socket read timed out**

**3) Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out**

Решил сделать запрос напрямик в jsp через jdbc драйвер, также ошибка связи. Ребуты Tomcat7 не помогают решить данную проблему, бывает когда через определенное время проблема уходит сама, бывает что через время нужно ребутить сервер. Сам сервер БД пингуется и запросы на стороне работают. БД Oracle, драйвер скачан с офф. сайта и подключен в maven, и hibernate, если нужно больше инвы напишите какой, я предоставлю. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста, всем большое спасибо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679108/java-sql-sqexception-io-exception-socket-read-timed-out-vs-closed-connection   Может Ваш случай?

Comment: Не совсем, там описано как пробудить сокет через jdbc а как сделать тоже самое только через hibernate ? или я чего-то не правильно понял ?

Comment: Хибернейт работает поверх JDBC. Может вам connection пул использовать? От многих проблем избавит. Почитайте [Connection Testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing), [Configuring Recovery From Database Outages](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_recovery)

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы.